# How to replace 'any strings' with nan in pandas DataFrame using a boolean mask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a 227x4 DataFrame with country names and numerical values to clean (wrangle ?).

Here's an abstraction of the DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import string
import numpy as np
pdn = pd.DataFrame(["".join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(3)]) for j in range (6)], columns =['Country Name'])
measures = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(10,size=(6,2)), columns=['Measure1','Measure2'])
df = pdn.merge(measures, how= 'inner', left_index=True, right_index =True)

df.iloc[4,1] = 'str'
df.iloc[1,2] = 'stuff'
print(df)

  Country Name Measure1 Measure2
0          tua        6        3
1          MDK        3    stuff
2          RJU        7        2
3          WyB        7        8
4          Nnr      str        3
5          rVN        7        4
```

How do I replace string values with `np.nan` in all columns without touching the country names?

I tried using a boolean mask:

```
mask = df.loc[:,measures.columns].applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float))).values
print(mask)

[[ True  True]
 [ True False]
 [ True  True]
 [ True  True]
 [False  True]
 [ True  True]]

# I thought the following would replace by default false with np.nan in place, but it didn't
df.loc[:,measures.columns].where(mask, inplace=True)
print(df)

  Country Name Measure1 Measure2
0          tua        6        3
1          MDK        3    stuff
2          RJU        7        2
3          WyB        7        8
4          Nnr      str        3
5          rVN        7        4


# this give a good output, unfortunately it's missing the country names
print(df.loc[:,measures.columns].where(mask))

  Measure1 Measure2
0        6        3
1        3      NaN
2        7        2
3        7        8
4      NaN        3
5        7        4
```

I have looked at several questions related to mine ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440991/pandas-dataframe-boolean-mask-on-multiple-columns), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519140/pandas-dataframe-set-value-on-boolean-mask), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe?s=1|181.1213), [[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe), [[5]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383094/python-pandas-numpy-true-false-to-1-0-mapping?s=1|94.6631), [[6]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29686046/python-pandas-filter-method-using-boolean-mask?s=1|69.9785), [[7]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035652/how-to-load-an-excel-sheet-and-clean-the-data-in-python?s=1|33.3427), [[8]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37837148/replaces-spaces-with-nan-in-pandas-dataframe)), but could not find one that answered my concern.

Comment: "A meta-question, Is it normal that it takes me more than 3 hours to formulate a question here (including research) ?" – Yes. The success of [so] and the entire Stack Exchange network is predicated on the high quality of its content, both questions and answers. You can't throw together a high quality question in a couple of minutes. Personally, I'd put the required effort more on the order of days than hours. I certainly have spent an entire day or more on an answer, and I expect the asker to expend at least an order of magnitude more effort, since he's the one getting the benefit.

Comment: Side note: meta-questions should be asked on [meta].

Comment: @JörgWMittag  I was just counting the time put to write the question after I gave up trying on my own.  If I had to count that it would be in days indeed. I'll make a question in meta when I have a few more hours in front of me.  I was feeling dumb taking so much time to ask my question.  But I feel better now and the quality of the answer is a proof that it was well worth the effort.  Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assign only columns of interest:

```
cols = ['Measure1','Measure2']
mask = df[cols].applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float)))

df[cols] = df[cols].where(mask)
print (df)
  Country Name Measure1 Measure2
0          uFv        7        8
1          vCr        5      NaN
2          qPp        2        6
3          QIC       10       10
4          Suy      NaN        8
5          eFS        6        4
```

> A meta-question, Is it normal that it takes me more than 3 hours to formulate a question here (including research) ?

In my opinion yes, create good question is really hard.

Comment: I like you asnwer, but why  `df2= df.loc[:,measures.columns].where(mask, inplace=True)` does not do the replacement ?  While `df.loc[:,measures.columns].where(mask)` prints out correctly.

Comment: Because `inplace` always return `None`, so `df2` is None

Comment: I've edited the question.. I don't understand why df.loc[:,measures.columns].where(mask, inplace=True) does not modify df ?

Comment: I think there is problem with assign to copy of `df`, same problem like `fillna` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43642196/2901002). If change your code to `df[measures.columns].where(mask)` get warning.

Answer (score 14):

Use numeric with errors coerce i.e

```
cols = ['Measure1','Measure2']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')
```

```
 Country Name  Measure1  Measure2
0          PuB       7.0       6.0
1          JHq       2.0       NaN
2          opE       4.0       3.0
3          pxl       3.0       6.0
4          ouP       NaN       4.0
5          qZR       4.0       6.0
```

Comment: I think we can get rid of `lambda` in this case: `df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='corece')`

Comment: @Bharathshetty, your answer is too good (if that is possible).  I will indeed coerce the string to numeric values but this was not clear to me when I formulated the question.  My focus was on how to use the boolean mask and why the inplace did not work.

Comment: @Bharathshetty I think one should read `errors=coerce` instead of `errors=corece`

Comment: That was a small typo. Sorry for that

Answer (score 9):

```
cols = ['Measure1','Measure2']
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(lambda x: x if not isinstance(x, str) else np.nan)
```

or

```
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(lambda x: np.nan if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```

Result:

```
In [22]: df
Out[22]:
  Country Name  Measure1  Measure2
0          nBl      10.0       9.0
1          Ayp       8.0       NaN
2          diz       4.0       1.0
3          aad       7.0       3.0
4          JYI       NaN      10.0
5          BJO       9.0       8.0
```

Comment: But why the negation `x if not isinstance(x, str)` instead of `x if isinstance(int,float) else `np.nan` ?

Comment: That will replace all numbers with nan if you dont need negation then `x: np.nan if isinstance(x, str) else x`

Comment: I don't want to replace number.. I want to replace non numbers with nan

Comment: @MalikKoné, I think you want to use  [Bharath shetty's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47001627/5741205)

Comment: All three answers are very interesting for me... My focus is on understanding I don't have to optimization of physical resources yet. :o)

Comment: @MalikKoné, if your goal is to clean up numeric columns - i.e. replace all values to numeric dtypes, and replacing those that can't be converted to numeric dtypes to NaN's, then  Bharath shetty's solution is the most idiomatic approach. If you want to replace cells of specific dtypes with NaN's then you can choose between jezrael's and mine solution...